# Laravel pretty url in edit method

Tags: laravel, laravel-route

can someone tell me how can I still have pretty URL when trying to edit my post? I have slugs etc but for edit method, we need to use GET|HEAD which means we will have something like this:

[www.our-domen.com/admin/posts/this-is-my-post-for-edit/edit?_token=0GXpk4oaLdGy8YOdp0591ogAOIHF89ZCciWk79h&btn-editPost=](http://www.our-domen.com/admin/posts/this-is-my-post-for-edit/edit?_token=0GXpk4oaLdGy8YOdp0591ogAOIHF89ZCciWk79h&btn-editPost=)

Instead of this:

[www.our-domen.com/admin/posts/this-is-my-post-for-edit/edit](http://www.our-domen.com/admin/posts/this-is-my-post-for-edit/edit)

Here is the part of the code:

```
<td>
  <form action="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->slug) }}" method="get">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" name="btn-editPost" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="color: white;">Edit</button>
  </form>
</td>
```

**Note** : slugs are set up correctly, it is not a problem :)

Comment: Change `method="get"` to `method="post"` And  also change your route `get` to `post`

Comment: I use resource route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the  [form](/questions/tagged/form) actually, if you just delete `@csrf`, it will work.

Or, change your code :

```
<td>
   <form action="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->slug) }}" method="get">
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" name="btn-editPost" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="color: white;">Edit</button>
   </form>
<td>
```

To,

```
<td>
   <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->slug) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="color: white;">Edit</a>
</td>
```